# Calling "argocd login" fails with "Local config: current-context unset"

Tags: linux, go, permissions

one of our clients is encountering a strange bug when running our cli binary. i narrowed down the error to a call we are making for `argocd login`, which for some reason fails with

```
Local config: current-context unset
```

from digging deeper into argo-cd source code, i *suspect* it all boils down to a call for `os.ReadFile` with `""`, which *does not* return ENOENT on their machine. i have made this simple check:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    _, err := os.ReadFile("")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("err: %v\n", err)
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            fmt.Println("err is NotExist")
        } else {
            fmt.Println("err is *not* NotExist")
        }
    } else {
        fmt.Println("no error at all")
    }
}
```

on every linux distro i tested it on, i am getting `err is NotExist`. but i suspect the issue might be caused by the specific env the customers are running in. all i know at the moment is that they shell into EC2, and then into some in-house docker container, and run the command as root user.

does anyone here have any tip on what i can look for, and what might cause this call to *not* return ENOENT?

Answer (score 1):

`os.ReadFile` passes the filename directly to the open(2) system call. If `os.ReadFile("")` is not returning `ENOENT`, that implies:

- a non-standard file system implementation from the kernel (eg, something custom via Fuse), or
- a syscall hook forcing a different result from the kernel (eg, EBPF)

Answer (score 0):

has same issue in gcp cloudbuild, fixed by removing some steps before argocd step ‍♂️